# iOS Charts library and LineChart xAxis

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart, ios-charts

I'm trying to create a **LineChartView** with values representing expenses for the current quarter. I need to print months and days with a customs number of labels for the xAxis. Unfortunately, the *LineChart* is generating a set of entries that don't suit my needs and I cannot change them. I need the grid lines at my custom positions that are the first day of the month and a set of days for the month and I want them at specific positions not where the *LineChart* wants. I've checked the code and seen that the entry values for the xAxis are calculated in `XAxisRenderer.computeAxisValues` and it looks like I have no way to specify their number and positions. The number of labels that I set it is not taken into account, and I do not have time to customize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways might achieve what you needed:

1. Set the number of labels for x-axis, for example,

   ```
   let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
   xAxis.labelCount = 7
   //xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
   ```

   Through this, exactly 7 grid lines as will be drawn, if you set
   drawLabelsEnabled as false, the min and max lines will be added in
   additional to those 7
2. Use limit lines

   You can disable the drawing of grid lines, and use limit lines
   instead. In this way, you can draw line for whatever values you
   need, for example,

   ```
   let limitLine = ChartLimitLine(limit: xValue, label:
   labelForThisLine)
   limitLine.lineWidth = 0.5
   limitLine.lineColor = .black
   limitLine.valueTextColor = .black
   chartView.xAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine)
   ```

Comment: Hi alanio. I'll try the second option. The first one doesn't work. If you have, for example,  minValue = 0, maxValue=400 and labelCount = 25, there will be 15 entries at positions calculated by the AxisRenderBase.computeAxisValues and it doesn't take into considerations my labels. I didn't try the LimiLine options tough.... I'll check that. Thank you

Comment: UPDATE: Just tried the limit-lines... you ... deserve to get the Nobel price ! In the meantime you get my up-vote and the check on the answer.... thank you so much !